# “Sbarcare da un ascensore” è gergo tecnico oppure viene usato anche nel linguaggio comune?

Tags: word-usage

Recentemente ho trovato questo cartello appeso all'interno di un ascensore:

[image]

Ovviamente è diventato la barzelletta del giorno, in ufficio, e qualche buontempone poco dopo ha fatto una piccola aggiunta:

[image]

Facendo una ricerca su Google, però, ho visto che diversi siti parlano di *sbarco* in relazione agli ascensori, quindi penso sia un'espressione corretta: è solo un gergo da ascensorista o si usa anche normalmente?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***[Sbarco](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&q=sbarco%20da%20ascensore&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAv-S2spbRAhWed1AKHVZkBnAQvwUIFigA&biw=768&bih=909)/sbarcare***  da un ascensore  è un'espressione tecnica come si può vedere dai vari esempi presenti in rete.

Da [ancivarese.it](http://www.anacivarese.it/images/sponsor/genesia/sbarchi.pdf):

> - ***Il problema degli sbarchi diretti di un ascensore*** in un appartamento, o comunque ***di uno sbarco chiuso all' interno di*** ... Questo obbligo assoluto è stato successivamente parzialmente ammorbidito da diversi pareri del.

- Comunemente si dice "***scendere/uscire" da un ascensore.***